# Getting previous UIViewController swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I want to get previous `viewController`.

I have 2 `UIViewControllers` and `navigationMenu` when I select any row from `navigation` menu i want to get UIViewController from where menu opened to move to the second `UIViewController`.

I want to know how to get previous `UIViewController` in this case

I tried this but count return `nil`:

```
 let n: Int! = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count
 print(n)
 let myUIViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[n-2] as! UIViewController
```

Edit:-

opening menu code

```
  let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title :"open", style: .plain, target: self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
```

Comment: which library are you using for the menu ?

Comment: SWRevealViewController

Comment: ok you want to know only at one place or you want to know from any file ?

Comment: i want to know how to get ViewController from where menu opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by saving UIViewController from where menu opened in delegate so i can access it from anywhere

Comment: @Rashwan L this is my answer

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can get the previous `viewController`, check the comments for explanations:

```
// get all the viewControllers to start with
if let controllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
    // iterate through all the viewControllers
    for (index, controller) in controllers.enumerated() {
        // when you find your current viewController
        if controller == self {
            // then you can get index - 1 in the viewControllers array to get the previous one
            let myUIViewController = controllers[index-1]
            print(controllers[index-1])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i open menu using this way
     let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title :"open", style: .plain, 
    target: self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
so no Navigation controller used thats why count returns nil and when i tried your code dosn't print anything also

Comment: it's a good answer but didn't help me in this case i wrote my answer (way that helped me)

Answer (score 1):

Add a variable of First ViewController type in Second ViewController .

```
class SecondViewController : UIViewController 
{
   var previousVC = FirstViewController()
}
```

Now perform segue to Second ViewController from First ViewController .

```
 performSegue(withIdentifier: "to2nd", sender: self) //to2nd or Your Choice
```

In prepare segue function put your First view Controller object into target .

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) 
{
        if segue.identifier == "to2nd" // Or you segue id name 
        {
            if let target = segue.destination as? SecondViewController
            {
                target.previousVC = self
            }
        }
}
```

And now whenever you need previous ViewController or its data , use `previousVC`

Comment: see edit post
i don't use prepare for segue i want to get UIViewController where menu opened

Comment: do you know how to write this line in objective c    var previousVC = FirstViewController()

Answer (score 1):

if your ViewControllers are embedded into a NavigationController, you can use the standard popViewController function in your second VC:

```
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 5.x

Suppose you are in `SecondViewController` and you want to check if the previous view controller is really  `FirstViewController`, so  you can do:

```
if let prevIndex = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.firstIndex(where: {$0 == self })?.advanced(by: -1) {
   if let prevVC = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[prevIndex], prevVC is FirstViewController {
      // do whatever you want with prevVC
   }
}
```